# Bringing a form to the front after creating it in a different thread

Tags: c#

I start a form with

```
if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().Count() > 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("form is open");
    //I want to bring the from to the top sine it is already running
}
else
{
    System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(ThreadProc1));
    t.Start();
}

public static void ThreadProc1()
{
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

I want to bring the form to the top if it is already started
and not just splash a message box that the form is open.
I have done search's and cant seem to find a solution that works

Comment: I don't think there's a good reason to use threads here, create a public static Form member in your Program class; then if you need to show it on a press of a button or whatever use: Program.myFrom.Show() and/or BringToFront()

Comment: You can't create forms (or manipulate them) from background threads. You will get a cross thread exception error. UI operations must be performed on the one and only UI thread.

Comment: That explain the problem error

Comment: I changed the code to

     if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().Count() > 0)
              {
                  MessageBox.Show("form is open");
                  Application.OpenForms["PO"].BringToFront();

            }
            else
            {

                Form1 myForm = new Form1();
                myForm.Name = "PO"; //Set the Form Name
                myForm.Show();
                
            }

and now I get what I was looking for the form pops starts the first time then just pops up if the user trys to restart the form....I am VERY new to C# thanks !!

Comment: What happened to the other answer it did not work with my original code but it sure helped me figure out what to do!!